# SOLR: special sorting of products, first on still active (by date), then on created_at

Tags: java, sorting, solr

We have a Solr index with products, which we show in our search results on our website. On the website these results are shown in two seperate groups: active and non-active.

**Active:**
Where column valid_to is greater than the current date and time.

**Non-active:**
Where column valid_to is older than the current date and time.

We could add a column to the documents called "active" and sort on this column, but we would like the results real-time. So just sorting on `valid_to DESC` solves the problem right, put all first products in active till you are at a product with an older valid_to date than the current date and time and put that product and the rest in non-active. Problem solved.

But, we would like to sort the products inside the Active group as well, on new to old, so we would like to sort these on `created_at DESC`. Now this obviously doesn't work:

http://solrurl:8080/select?q=searchterm&sort=valid_to%20desc,created_at%20desc

So anyone who knows a method to fix this sort method?

Comment: Two successive queries (one for active products, sorted by created_at, and one for inactive products, sorted by created_at) would work.

Comment: Ok, so one query isn't possible? Cause I read something about Function Queries. But I can't really figure out or it's possible to get it done with Function Queries: http://wiki.apache.org/solr/FunctionQuery

Comment: I think you can, by sorting via a subquery, but the syntax is quite obscure. These two links have related examples: http://lucene.472066.n3.nabble.com/Syntax-for-sorting-by-a-sub-query-td4043740.html and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12749669/conditional-sorting-in-solr-3-6